# GroupBox y CheckBox c# winforms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, checkbox

Tengo un `groupbox` con varios `checkbox` dentro, lo que quiero hacer es recorrer todos los `checkbox` y obtener su estado y ver si esta seleccionada o no y guardar en una variable ese resultado `(checked = 1, no checked = 0)` para después utilizar esa variable y enviar a la BD el estado de cada uno de los `checkbox`.

Ejemplo:
`Groupbox1` dentro tengo:

```
Checkbox2
Checkbox3
Checkbox4
Checkbox5
Checkbox6
Checkbox7
```

Gracias.

Comment: si se puede con un foreach... perame busco la sintaxis ya te indico

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta seria mi solución, prueba a ver si te funciona:

```
private class checkedBox
{
    public string name;
    public bool status;
}

List<checkedBox> listChekedBox;

public void findCheckedBox(GroupBox group)
{
    listChekedBox = new List<checkedBox>();
    foreach (Control control in group.Controls)
    {
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
        {
            checkedBox box = new checkedBox();
            box.name = control.Name;
            box.status = ((CheckBox)control).Checked;
            listChekedBox.Add(box);
        }
    }
}
```

Si lo quieres exactamente como lo indicas solo debes cambiar el tipo de variable a entero:

```
private class checkedBox
{
    public string name;
    public int status;
}

List<checkedBox> listChekedBox;

public void findCheckedBox(GroupBox group)
{
    listChekedBox = new List<checkedBox>();
    foreach (Control control in group.Controls)
    {
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
        {
            checkedBox box = new checkedBox();
            box.name = control.Name;
            box.status = ((CheckBox)control).Checked ? 1 : 0;
            listChekedBox.Add(box);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mira, aqui te dejo un ejemplo que puedes implentar en tu proyeto, en el cual se recorren los forms de un panel:

```
int[] check =new int[5];
            foreach (Control ct in this.groupbox)
            {
                if (ct is CheckBox)
                {
                    if (((CheckBox)ct).Checked)
                    {
                        check[0] = 1;
                    }
                }
             }
```

declaras un array en el cual vas almacenando los valores y luego cuando vas a insertar en la BD puede recorres el array y extraer su respetivo valor.